# Laravel 5.7 create empty project

Tags: laravel

i've worked with with 5.4, but i'm lost since 5.7 version.
When in want to start a new project i've lot of features like Authentification already generated and some javascript stuff with webpack and Vue.js
And by default, i see that '/' url is protected by authenfication middleware.

laravel list command print

```
Usage:
  command [options] [arguments]

Options:
  -h, --help            Display this help message
  -q, --quiet           Do not output any message
  -V, --version         Display this application version
      --ansi            Force ANSI output
      --no-ansi         Disable ANSI output
  -n, --no-interaction  Do not ask any interactive question
  -v|vv|vvv, --verbose  Increase the verbosity of messages: 1 for normal output, 2 for more verbose output and 3 for debug

Available commands:
  help  Displays help for a command
  list  Lists commands
  new   Create a new Laravel application.
```

But what's if i just want a minimalist project ?
I doesn't want to create an API, so i doesn't want Lumen. Just create an application with the possibility to use authentification scaffold, templeting engine blade and let me configure webpack myself without vue.js by default if i want to use react with typescript by example.

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/mix#react
try this link from the documentation to get react to work with laravel. You basically have to install the framework according to the documentation and then customize for your needs.

Comment: https://mattstauffer.com/blog/removing-all-vue-dependencies-from-laravel/ is a link where you could remove vue.js from laravel.

Comment: This is very frustrating indeed and I wish there was a way to have a real empty project.. I'm new to Laravel so if I want to make a simple project, I still end up with lots of garbage that I don't know if I can delete or not with my lack of experience. I would prefer a simple "Hello World" page

Answer (score 0):

Since Laravel 6 you can add UI and auth as additional option.

```
laravel new abc
composer require laravel/ui
php artisan ui [bootstrap, vue, react] --auth
```

Please, look for it to documentation:

https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/frontend